# Where it comes from func(x)?

Tags: javascript

guys please who can explain func(x) what is and where it comes from ? How did it become a function name?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `slow` function was sent as a delegate (that it, callback) to the `cachingDecorator` function. Therefore, it is executable.